# how to pass the two array?

Tags: php

The `test.php` directory is the same as csv and text file. now i want to pass all the `csv file name` and `all the text name`  to the following `if` condition. namely, replace `one.csv` with all the csv file name. replace `one.txt` with all the txt file name.

```
if (($handle = fopen("one.csv", "r")) !== FALSE && ($handle2 = fopen("one.txt", 'a')) !== FALSE) { ...}
```

the following is my code. after run the code,i found all the content in the **text** file are the same. it loops too many times. how to change the code?thank you.

```
    $files = glob("./*.csv");
    $files1 = glob("./*.txt");
    foreach($files as $filepath){
    foreach($files1 as $filepath1){


   $row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("one.csv", "r")) !== FALSE && ($handle2 = fopen("one.txt", 'a')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($row > 1) {
            $url = $data[8];
            foreach($result[0] as $url){
                fwrite($handle2, $url."\r\n");
            }

        }
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($handle2);
}

    }
    }
```

The txt file is empty. now, i want to read the csv file and extract some content of it then put them into the text file. thank you

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Could you re-phrase your question so it makes more sense, please?

Comment: I think he wants to open all files in his script's directory which have a `.txt` or a `.csv` extension.

Comment: Do you want to open a `.csv` file with the `.txt` which has the same filename or not ...?

Comment: the aim i want to do is open csv file and write some content into txt file

Comment: Ah, and what do you want to write in the .txt file ? The content of the .csv file which has the same filename thant the .txt file ? We would appreciate a little more details here.

Comment: i add all of my code on the original questions. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to glob .txt files, just glob csv, and replace the extension `.csv` by `.txt`

```
$csv = glob('./*.csv');
foreach($csv as $file) {
   $txt = preg_replace('#\.csv$#', '.txt', $file);
   if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE && ($handle2 = fopen($txt, 'a')) !== FALSE) {
    //your code...
    }
}
```

Comment: if i merge the two arrary. then i don't know how to pass them into if (($handle = fopen("one.csv", "r")) !== FALSE && ($handle2 = fopen("one.txt", 'a')) !== FALSE)

Comment: namely, to replace the one.csv and one.txt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've got a loop within a loop. So every time the first loop loops it's doing everything in the second loop AGAIN.

Try something like this:

```
$csv_files = glob("./*.csv");
$txt_files = glob("./*.txt");

$csvs = array();
foreach($csv_files as $fp){
    $csvs[] = fopen($fp, "r");
}

$txts = array();
foreach($txt_files as $fp){
    $txts[] = fopen($fp, "r");
}

var_dump($csvs); // all csv file info
var_dump($txts); // all txt file info
```

You can test to see `!== false` in the separate loops if you wish. Otherwise, if you just want to use them then you can loop through the separate arrays and get the info out of them that way.

Comment: I've written this assuming that you want to keep your CSVs and your TXTs separate. However you can do what @Bartimeus says and merge the two arrays at the start `$all_files = array_merge($csv_files, $txt_files);` and then you just need the one `foreach` loop. It won't make much difference performance wise but it may be more useful to you if you want to treat them all the same.

Comment: Yes, given the fact that we don't know what he wants to do, difficult to help him...